# Please help me with this simple script

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I have just started to learn native javascript and I am trying to write a simple script which will display an alert window showing the text contained in each `<p></p>` element.

I am posting the code below. Please let me know what I am doing wrong

```
function show(){
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  for(i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    x[i].onclick=function(){
      alert(x[i].innerText);
    }
  }
}

show()
```

HTML is below:

```
<p>Blackberry</p>
<p>Strawberry</p>
<p>Raspberry</p>
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you are leaking a global `i` which is a really bad thing. Use `var i`! The second thing I notice is that you do not mention what's actually happening (nothing, error, etc.)

Comment: The main problem is that `i` leaking into closure.

Comment: A bigger issue is show is likely called before the html is rendered

Answer (score 3):

You're referencing an undefined object inside your callback, use:

```
alert(this.innerText || this.textContent);
```

instead...

**edit**: as pointed by [@Sarfraz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139459/sarfraz) check for both innerText or textContent properties to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

PS
Check also that `show();` is called when the referenced DOM is loaded, and not before ;)

Comment: Notice that `innerText` is not cross browser. You should use `innerHTML` or `innerText || textContent`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call show onload - for example

`window.onload=show;`

and change `x[i]` to `this` in the onclick - [innerText](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04) is not supported by all browsers

I would do this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/shyxX/)

```
window.onload=function(){
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    x[i].onclick=function(){
      alert(this.innerHTML); // supported by more browsers than innerText
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it deleted my comment, checked it to be working fine, +1 :)

Comment: Thanks :) - updated my fiddle to use the innerText/textContent version

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure proper scoping of `i` inside your function.
You also need to use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`.

```
function show() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            x[i].onclick = function () {
                alert(x[i].innerHTML);
            }
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Since inside the `onclick` handler `this` is bound to the element, you can also avoid the issue with the closure and `i` alltogether:

```
function show() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].onclick = function() {
            alert(this.innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the need for ()() in this case and why no this?

Comment: The second solution does use `this`. In the first one the function call is necessary to avoid i being always the last value when the callback is actually called.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you used the `<script>` tag in `<head>`. This will often fail because the DOM is not fully loaded.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
  function show(){....}
  show(); // don't do this 
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Blackberry</p>
  <p>Strawberry</p>
  <p>Raspberry</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

It's better to use `window.onload = show;` or `window.addEventListener('load',show);`.

However, `x[i]` is a local variable. It isn't known outside of show, not even in your anonymous function. So you have to create a closure or use `this.innerHTML`.

So either use

```
function show(){
   var el = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
   for(var i = 0; i < el.lenght; ++i){
       el[i].onclick = function(e){
           alert(this.innerHTML);
       }
   }
}
window.onload = show;
```

or

```
function show(){
   var el = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
   for(var i = 0; i < el.lenght; ++i){
       el[i].onclick = (function(element){
           return function(e){
               alert(element.innerHTML);
           };
       })(el[i]);
   }
}
window.onload = show;
```

See also:

- [MDN: `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler)
- [MDN: Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is closure, otherwise any `<p>`, when clicked would not return anything as after iteration, `i` becomes `x.length + 1`, thus you are trying to access a non existant element when trying to do

`x[i].innerText`

Change your code to:

```
function show(){

   var x = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

   for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
      x[i].onclick=function(i){
          return function() {
              alert(x[i].innerHTML); // alternatively you can also do this.innerHTML without closure, I just wanna introduce you to this concept
          }
       }(i);
   }


}

show()​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3xYtF/11/

Or alternatively you can change `x[i].innerText` to `this.innerText` without having to use closure, but I see this as a good opportunity to introduce the concept of closure :). Also as pointed in another comment, `.innerText` isn't really crossbrowser, use `innerText || textContent`

Comment: OP said: _I have just started to learn native javascript and I am trying to write a simple script_ - and we lay closure on him?

Comment: Added a disclaimer.. :S, but I don't see any problem with introducing that early on. Thanks for your reminder though :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, whenever the click handler is executed, it will always point to the last value of i. So, whatever paragraph element you click on you will always see 'Raspberry' according to your example.

The cleanest way to fix this, without using any complicated closure (which takes up memory), is to use 'this,' the context identifier, which will point to the element which is clicked on.

function show(){

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){

    x[i].onclick=function(){

        alert(this.innerText);

    }

}
```

}

show()

Answer (score 0):

I think `show()`is being run *before* the page has fully loaded. Try calling the function from the `onload`event instead and see if that helps.

`<body onload='show();'>`